# Overriding with object or string as argument

Tags: java, function, object, inheritance

We expect "ACBD" for output with that code but we get "ACBB". Why?

```
class A{
public void f(Object o){
    System.out.println("A");
}
}
class B{
   public void f(String s){
    System.out.println("B");
}
}
class C extends A{
  public void f(String s){
    System.out.println("C");
}
}
 class D extends B{
  public void f(Object o){
    System.out.println("D");
}
}
public class JavaApplication40 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a=new C(); a.f("mee");
     C c=new C(); c.f("mee");
     B b=new D(); b.f("mee");
     D d=new D(); d.f("mee");
  }
  }
```

I think a must call f of class A, c must call f of class C, b must call f from class B, d must call f from class D. But it looks like that it's change wit argument of function. Why?

Comment: The difference is Super Class A has Object as an argument in function f, but B has a String as an argument type. For your expectation of ACBD, you need to interchange the argument types of B and D to Object and String respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the method's identity is tied not only to its name but also to its set of parameters. That is,

```
public void f(Object o)
```

and

```
public void f(String s)
```

are separate methods in `D`. Java determines which one to execute at runtime, based on the type of parameter you give it. You're not actually overriding any methods in this example, just adding new ones with similar names but different parameter sets.

Note that, in all your test cases, Java chooses the object that's closest to `String`. If a version of the method takes a `String` and another version takes an `Object`, then the more specific `String` will win out.

If you instead call `d.f(a)`, or with any other object that isn't a string, then you should see it print `"D"`. Similarly, if you call `b.f(a)` with any argument that isn't a string, it should print `"A"`.

Comment: Note that you get `"AC"` but also `"BB"` because the location of the `f(Object)` method (in the superclass or the subclass) is different between A/C and B/D.

Comment: You get the first "A" (so you call a method with Object parameter), although C instance which is stored in `a` variable has both methods, and by your logic it should've printed "C" (I explained this behavior in my answer).

Comment: But string is object too. Why call that have String as argument?

Answer (score 1):

Since class `D` extends class `A`, and you are passing `String` as the parameter, it will take the method with the parameter that matches your input in `d.f("mee")` - namely `public void f(String s)`.

On the other hand, if in class 'D' function wasn't `public void f(Object o)`, but `public void f(String s)`, you would have gotten `"D"` as output in the log.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between overloading and overriding. In your code you use overloading methods (creating methods with the same name but different parameter types). Overloading is resolved by compiler at compile time (unlike overriding, which is resolved at runtime).

For `a`, compiler sees that its type is A, so it chooses A method.

For `c`, compiler sees that its types is C, so it chooses the method with the most specific signature, which is C method (String is more specific than Object).

For `b`, compiler sees that its type is B, so it chooses B method.

For `d`, compiler sees that its type is D, so it chooses the method with the most specific signature, which is B method (String is more specific than Object).

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter, `"mee"` is closest to `String` than to `Object` and therefore,

```
public void f(String s){
    System.out.println("B");
}
```

is chosen over

```
public void f(Object o){
    System.out.println("D");
}
```

If you are expecting `ACBB`, you need to define `D` as

```
class D extends B{
  public void f(String s){
    System.out.println("D");
}
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense.